# Log all API calls during the execution of an Android app

Tags: android

I want to collect all the API calls made by an Android app that runs on a real device (with root permissions, obvs).

With API call I mean the methods invoked on objects like:
[ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

I thought that I can instrument all methods with the Xposed framework but maybe exists a simpler way... a kind of "high-level strace".

Otherwise it's sufficient to monitor the stacktrace...

What do you suggest?

Comment: You mean something similar to what running a process through `strace` gives you on an ordinary Linux system with a reasonably complete terminal userspace?

Comment: It would be perfect... but I don't know how you can do it with the Android vm

Comment: I would expect not (and I'm not really familiar with this kind of development to start with), but it might give people a frame of reference for what you are looking for.

Comment: If you are into programming, I suggest JPDA, and there MethodEntryRequest to write a small debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see Binder methods and other strace functionality with -- http://newandroidbook.com/tools/jtrace.html

However, I think you are looking to intercept API calls with the -- https://github.com/AndroidHooker/hooker -- techniques. There are other hooking techniques such as with [IntroSpy](https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android) -- https://www.sensepost.com/blog/2016/android-hooking-with-introspy --  but they don't look as applicable to your situation.

You could run into situations where anti-hooking techniques are present -- http://d3adend.org/blog/?p=589, so I suggest having a way to replace that code and repackage the APK -- https://github.com/oguzhantopgul/AppManipulator

The book, Hacking Android, covers using both IntroSpy and the XposedFramework for hooking. I think you'll like the output log from the XposedBridgeAPI -- http://blog.attify.com/2015/01/04/xposed-framework-android-hooking/ -- and you can find its development documentation here -- https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial

Moreover, the book covers what is more-common practice for Android app reversers and penetration testers, which is use of the [Frida](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2016/03/frida-dynamic-code-instrumentation-toolkit/) tools. In particular, I think the appmon -- http://dpnishant.github.io/appmon/ -- extension is the most-relevant (supporting both root and non-root privileged access), but you also might take a look at the extended version of cycript from NowSecure -- https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2016/09/02/cycript-on-steroids-pumping-up-portability-and-performance-with-frida/

Comment: hooker, introspy, frida, etc. aren't working. I had lots of expectations on Frida but is too buggy and too undocumented.
So I think that I'll continue with Xposed.
Thanks for the answer...

Comment: @Simone Aonzo: Try this tutorial -- http://www.welivesecurity.com/2016/11/07/apk-analysis-using-appmon/ -- she made it look really easy to install

Comment: I tried it, but the monitored app crash because of Frida... I used Frida with several devices and Android versions imho is an unusable software

Comment: https://github.com/bmax121/BudHook

Comment: https://blog.talosintelligence.com/how-to-instrument-system-applications-on-android-stock-images/

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achieve global Java call collection is to instrument the ART/DVM of the Androis OS. Here you can find a minimal patching procedure to apply to the AOSP (5.0 Lollipop, working on 6.0 Marshmallow as well) to collect all Java calls of a targeted application :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478647/android-app-java-jni-call-hooking-strategies

You could then differentiate API calls from application calls with some regex.