# Bypassing Certificate/SSL Pinning using AppMon

Tags: tls, android, reverse-engineering, certificate-pinning

I'm trying to reverse engineer an app that has Native layer certificate pinning, I can't go that deep in to patching so I've been looking in to other available options, one i came accross was appmon, but the apk i built using appmon keeps crashing on load, i tried with multiple apps and multiple devices same issue,

My other question is, if i root the phone, can i bypass native layer certificate pinning?

Comment: Related question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149325/disable-or-bypass-ssl-pinning-certificate-pinning-on-android-6-0-1

Comment: Its a bit related but it does not answer my question 100% unfortunately, its specifically for AppMon as to why it crashes and if native layer can be bypassed using xposed and rooting